# DataTables - Use 'this' keyword in two different contexts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables

**Some background info:** I'm using DataTables with React and the functions/code below are in the componentDidMount() function following the DataTables declaration (instantiated as `dt` below).

I am trying to get the row data in DataTables and when I do this it kind of works - I am able to get the correct `startupId`, but `this.setState()` is undefined because `this` is undefined in the function:

```
dt.on( 'click', 'tr', function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
        var row = dt.row( tr );
        var startupId = row.data().id;
        this.setState({
            viewStartup: true
        });
    });
```

However, when I use an arrow function instead (seen below), I am able to use `this.setState()` properly, but the `startupId` becomes null:

```
dt.on( 'click', 'tr', () => {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
        var row = dt.row( tr );
        var startupId = row.data().id;
        this.setState({
            viewStartup: true
        });
    });
```

I think I have narrowed down the issue in the arrow function case to `$(this)` because in the arrow function case, `this` refers to a different context that is not the currently selected row like it is in the `function(){}` case.

To my knowledge, you can't change the context of `this` in JavaScript, so does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the correct `startupId` and also the correct `this.setState()` context? In other words, how do I use `this` in the same function but in two different contexts?

Pastebin links:

- index.html file: https://pastebin.com/vcVCJ7d9
- Table.js file: https://pastebin.com/0GdY5KfZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab a reference to the component separately from declaring the function and use that inside the anonymous function:

```js
const component = this;
dt.on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
  var row = dt.row( tr );
  var startupId = row.data().id;
  component.setState({
    viewStartup: true
  });
});
```

Comment: When I try to do this, I don't think the state is actually changing because after component.setState() is run, the render() method doesn't update/re-run like it should/normally does on state changes. Because all of the code you suggested is in componentDidMount(), I think it's only updating `component` and not the actual state that I want

Comment: If all you want to do is ensure it re-renders, call [`component.forceUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) instead. If `viewStartup` was already `true` then the component will not re-render. React does a simple diff of the state to decide whether to re-render.

Comment: `viewStartup` is false in my test cases. Where should I run `component.forceUpdate()`? Is it right after the `setState()`? Thanks

Comment: `setState` will result in a re-render if the state changes. When `viewStartup` goes from `false` -> `true`, the component will re-render. If you keep calling `setState({ viewStartup: true })` though, there's no change; React diffs the state and sees that nothing changed and won't re-render anything.

Comment: I misunderstood what  you meant initially but now it makes sense. Thanks!